# MySQL запрос: вывести строки с минимальной разницей в столбцах

Tags: запрос, mysql

Всем привет. Не могли бы вы помочь мне со следующим:
Имеется БД, в таблице которой три колонки (t1, t2, t3). Мне необходимо вывести из БД те строки, в которых минимальная разница между t1 и t2 или t1 и t3 равна пяти. А так как в сложных запросах я дуб дубом, у меня ничего не получается. Пытался, следуя логике, написать запрос - вышло вот такое вот неработающее убожество:

```
SELECT * FROM org WHERE MIN((t1-t2),(t1-t3)) = 5
```

Как оно должно выглядеть на самом деле? Объясните, пожалуйста.
PS: извините, не тот код вставил

Comment: Можете привести пример строки (t1, t2, t3), которая подойдет под ваше условие?

Comment: Да. Например
t1 = 20; t2 = 15; t3 = 10; - подходит, ибо t1-t2 = 5, и меньше разницы нет. А вот
t1 = 20; t2 = 15; t3 = 18 - не подходит, ибо минимальная разница уже будет 2. И это выводить не требуется.

Comment: @Юрий Смирнов

    Мне необходимо вывести из БД те строки, в которых минимальная разница между t1 и t2 или t1 и t3 равна пяти. 

И что это может значить? Т.е. минимальная от чего? Если в пределах одной строки, то

    select * from org where if(abs(t1-t2)>abs(t1-t3), abs(t1-t3), abs(t1-t2)) = 5;

А min -- агрегатная функция, и тут не подходит

Comment: Может быть кому нибудь пригодится полный текст Селекта:
SELECT * FROM org WHERE ((LEAST(YEAR(datacheckstart)-YEAR(datastart), YEAR(datacheckstart) - YEAR(datareg), YEAR(datacheckstart) - YEAR(datacheckend)) = 3) AND (MONTH(GREATEST(datareg,datastart,datacheckend)) < 9 )) OR (LEAST(YEAR(datacheckstart)-YEAR(datastart), YEAR(datacheckstart) - YEAR(datareg), YEAR(datacheckstart) - YEAR(datacheckend)) > 3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте такой запрос:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM org
  WHERE LEAST((t1-t2),(t1-t3)) = 5;
```

**UPD: Переписал запрос с использованием функции LEAST (аналог MIN)**

Comment: Очень неплохой вариант. Но меня интересовала именно конструкция с MIN. Три колонки в таблице и разность = 5 я написал для передачи идеи. На деле колонок будет больше, и сравниваться будут даты. К тому же, еще будет одно условие: если эта разность в датах равна заданной, то нужно проверить день и месяц. И если все больше заданной разности, то их тоже потребуется вывести. Представляете, какой это придется запрос мне сейчас родить, если не получится разобраться с MIN? :)

Comment: А вот это уже кажется работает. Огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM org WHERE (t1-t2)>5 OR (t1-t3)>5
```

Может еще так, но не уверен

```
SELECT * FROM org WHERE (t1-5)>ANY(t2,t5)
```

Comment: Тогда скорее не AND а OR, потому что в условии: "разница между t1 и t2 или t1 и t3".

И "равно 5", а не больше.

Comment: Мне нужно именно, где минимальная разница пяти будет равна. Могут быть разницы и меньше, и больше. А вот те поля, в которых разница минимальная именно равна пяти, и нужно вывести на экран

Comment: Ну раз по модулю тут еще функция ABS() в помощь

Comment: Спасибо, но по модулю не будет. t1 всегда будет содержать значение большее, чем в t2 и t3. И вопрос мой был не в этом совсем